Chain Link Automation not work! No Execute
This my solidy code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface AutomationCompatibleInterface {
  function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata checkData) external returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory performData);
  function performUpkeep(bytes calldata performData) external;
}

// File: AutoCtr.sol

// File: @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/KeeperCompatibleInterface.sol

pragma solidity 0.8.19;

import {VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/dev/VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus.sol";
import {VRFV2PlusClient} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/dev/libraries/VRFV2PlusClient.sol";

/* Errors */
error Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(uint256 currentBalance, uint256 numPlayers, uint256 raffleState);
error Raffle__TransferFailed();
error Raffle__SendMoreToEnterRaffle();
error Raffle__RaffleNotOpen();

/**
 * Request testnet LINK and ETH here: https://faucets.chain.link/
 * Find information on LINK Token Contracts and get the latest ETH and LINK faucets here: https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/
 */

/**
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT THAT USES HARDCODED VALUES FOR CLARITY.
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT THAT USES UN-AUDITED CODE.
 * DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION.
 */

contract Lottery is VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus, AutomationCompatibleInterface {
    /* Type declarations */
    enum RaffleState {
        OPEN,
        CALCULATING
    }
    // Lottery Variables
    uint256 private immutable i_entranceFee;
    uint256 private s_lastTimeStamp;
    address payable[] private s_players;
    address private s_recentWinner;
    uint256 private immutable i_interval;
    RaffleState private s_raffleState;

    event RequestSent(uint256 requestId, uint32 numWords);
    event RequestFulfilled(uint256 requestId, uint256[] randomWords);
    event RaffleEnter(address indexed player);
    event WinnerPicked(address indexed player);
    event RequestedRaffleWinner(uint256 indexed requestId, bytes performData);

    // Your subscription ID.
    uint256 public immutable s_subscriptionId =
        78560131474220272056099479679342269674716447265552668612386115994028644171414;

    // Past request IDs.
    uint256[] public requestIds;
    uint256 public lastRequestId;

    // The gas lane to use, which specifies the maximum gas price to bump to.
    // For a list of available gas lanes on each network,
    // see https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf/v2-5/supported-networks
    bytes32 public keyHash =
        0x787d74caea10b2b357790d5b5247c2f63d1d91572a9846f780606e4d953677ae;

    // Depends on the number of requested values that you want sent to the
    // fulfillRandomWords() function. Storing each word costs about 20,000 gas,
    // so 100,000 is a safe default for this example contract. Test and adjust
    // this limit based on the network that you select, the size of the request,
    // and the processing of the callback request in the fulfillRandomWords()
    // function.
    uint32 public callbackGasLimit = 2500000;

    // The default is 3, but you can set this higher.
    uint16 public requestConfirmations = 3;

    // For this example, retrieve 2 random values in one request.
    // Cannot exceed VRFCoordinatorV2_5.MAX_NUM_WORDS.
    uint32 public numWords = 1;

    /**
     * HARDCODED FOR SEPOLIA
     * COORDINATOR: 0x9DdfaCa8183c41ad55329BdeeD9F6A8d53168B1B
     * https://docs.chain.link/vrf/v2-5/supported-networks#sepolia-testnet
     */
    constructor(
        // uint256 subscriptionId,
        uint256 entranceFee,
        uint256 interval
    ) VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus(0x9DdfaCa8183c41ad55329BdeeD9F6A8d53168B1B) {
        // s_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        i_entranceFee = entranceFee;
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN;
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        i_interval = interval;
    }

    // Assumes the subscription is funded sufficiently.
    function _requestRandomWords()
        private
        onlyOwner
        returns (uint256 requestId)
    {
        // Will revert if subscription is not set and funded.
        requestId = s_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            VRFV2PlusClient.RandomWordsRequest({
                keyHash: keyHash,
                subId: s_subscriptionId,
                requestConfirmations: requestConfirmations,
                callbackGasLimit: callbackGasLimit,
                numWords: numWords,
                extraArgs: VRFV2PlusClient._argsToBytes(
                    VRFV2PlusClient.ExtraArgsV1({nativePayment: false})
                )
            })
        );
        requestIds.push(requestId);
        lastRequestId = requestId;
        emit RequestSent(requestId, numWords);
        return requestId;
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256,
        uint256[] calldata _randomWords
    ) internal override {
        uint256 indexOfWinner = _randomWords[0] % s_players.length;
        address payable recentWinner = s_players[indexOfWinner];
        s_recentWinner = recentWinner;
        s_players = new address payable[](0);
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN;
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        (bool success, ) = recentWinner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        // require(success, "Transfer failed");
        if (!success) {
            revert Raffle__TransferFailed();
        }
        emit WinnerPicked(recentWinner);
    }

    function enterRaffle() public payable {
        // require(msg.value >= i_entranceFee, "Not enough value sent");
        // require(s_raffleState == RaffleState.OPEN, "Raffle is not open");
        if (msg.value < i_entranceFee) {
            revert Raffle__SendMoreToEnterRaffle();
        }
        if (s_raffleState != RaffleState.OPEN) {
            revert Raffle__RaffleNotOpen();
        }
        s_players.push(payable(msg.sender));
        // Emit an event when we update a dynamic array or mapping
        // Named events with the function name reversed
        emit RaffleEnter(msg.sender);
    }

    /**
     * @dev This is the function that the Chainlink Keeper nodes call
     * they look for `upkeepNeeded` to return True.
     * the following should be true for this to return true:
     * 1. The time interval has passed between raffle runs.
     * 2. The lottery is open.
     * 3. The contract has ETH.
     * 4. Implicity, your subscription is funded with LINK.
     */
    function checkUpkeep(
        bytes memory checkData
    )
        public
        view
        override
        returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory /* performData */)
    {
        bool isOpen = RaffleState.OPEN == s_raffleState;
        bool timePassed = ((block.timestamp - s_lastTimeStamp) > i_interval);
        bool hasPlayers = s_players.length > 0;
        bool hasBalance = address(this).balance > 0;
        if (timePassed && isOpen && hasBalance && hasPlayers) {
            return (true, checkData);
        } else {
            return (false, checkData);
        }
    }

     /**
     * @dev Once `checkUpkeep` is returning `true`, this function is called
     * and it kicks off a Chainlink VRF call to get a random winner.
     */
    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata performData ) external override {
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.CALCULATING;
        uint256 requestId = _requestRandomWords();
        emit RequestedRaffleWinner(requestId, performData);
    }

    function getRaffleState() public view returns (RaffleState) {
        return s_raffleState;
    }

    function getNumWords() public view returns (uint256) {
        return numWords;
    }

    function getRecentWinner() public view returns (address) {
        return s_recentWinner;
    }

    function getPlayer(uint256 index) public view returns (address) {
        return s_players[index];
    }

    function getLastTimeStamp() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_lastTimeStamp;
    }

    function getInterval() public view returns (uint256) {
        return i_interval;
    }

    function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
        return i_entranceFee;
    }

    function getNumberOfPlayers() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_players.length;
    }
}


Contract address: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xfd2eA75f66493eCF7F45072E01254c6d8C403a35#readContract
Automation detail:
https://automation.chain.link/sepolia/3269845219509365492688127324933702012403758002781625898657947000998001276879
When reading contract, the method of checkData returns true, but performUpkeep did not execute.
Expect it to run automatically。
